# Returning the latest entries in PostgreSQL for multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a web app where a user can send messages to contacts stored on the database. On successful posting of a message, the contact details of the recipients are entered into another table. I'd like to make a query that will return the recipients of that message. These are the columns on the table:

```
| communication_id | first_name | last_name | telephone |
```

The communication_id is a foreign key and it is distinct for every different communication, not per individual. If for instance a user sends a message and there are 20 recipients, I'd like to get only those 20. All the 20 have the same communication_id

The query I have so far is

```
SELECT communication_id, first_name ||' ' || last_name AS recipient_name, telephone
FROM communications_sent
ORDER BY communication_id DESC
```

But as you all know that will return everything. Also I cannot `LIMIT` because some entries will be left out. I can't use `COUNT(*)>1` because even older communications have a count of greater than 1. How can I get the latest entries only? Could be one entry, could be 100.

An example output of my query above is:

```
|communication_id|recipient_name|telephone|
|       263      |   John Doe   |712100100|
|       263      |   Willy Bill |721001001|
|       262      |   Mary May   |700101010|
|       262      |   Joe Jimmy  |722111000|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want only one communication id but all recipients.  If so:

```
SELECT cs.communication_id, cs.first_name ||' ' || cs.last_name AS recipient_name, cs.telephone
FROM communications_sent cs
WHERE cs.communication_id = (SELECT MAX(cs2.communication_id)
                             FROM communications_sent cs2
                            )
ORDER BY cs.communication_id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. It worked. I have a question though, why does it have to be nested? If it is used as `SELECT MAX(cs.communication_id), ...` as the first argument, it outputs an error

Comment: @Clint_A . . . Because you cannot use aggregation functions in a `WHERE` clause.